# How to use prestashop color picker

Tags: prestashop

i am working on prestahop module and need to add `prestashop` default `color picker` in backend. Any assistance will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: If you want to add your own solution, please post it as an answer, not by editing the question. You can even accept it after some time. Also, no need to edit your title - the checkmark you've set is more than enough to indicate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i figured it out myself by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="'.__PS_BASE_URI__.'js/jquery/plugins/jquery.colorpicker.js"></script>
```

and where i wanted it to show

```
<input type="text" class="mColorPicker" id="color_0" value="#000000" data-hex="true" /><span id="icp_color_0" class="mColorPickerTrigger" data-mcolorpicker="true"><img src="../img/admin/color.png" /></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

More correct answer is add new color field to *public function renderForm()* in main module php file

```
array(                          'type' => 'color',
                                'label' => $this->l('Change Color'),
                                'name' => 'maincolor',
                                'lang' => false,
                                'id'   => 'color_0',
                                'data-hex' => true,
                                'class'   => 'mColorPicker',
                                'desc' => $this->l('Enter hex code.'),
                            ),
```